# How to indent back one level when writing a newline?

Tags: latex, indentation

I'm using Emacs to write LaTeX. For example, in the following code, I have write to the `level 3`. When I press `C-j`, the cursor will indent to the third level. I what the newline to be indent at `level 2`.

How would I be able to do this?

```
\level 1
\level 1
  \level 2
  \level 2
     \level 3
     \level 3
  \level 2 % <- I want to end up here
```

Update: Thanks, I'm using [sdaps](https://github.com/sdaps/sdaps) package to write a survey. Here is a question example. BTW, I don't know list environment yet. Is it related to this?

Comment: Can you give a real use case?  The only scenario where I think this is useful is within list environments, and AUCTeX has good list support.  This is more-or-less the default behavior when using proper lists.

Comment: Thanks :) Re 'list environments': a 'list' environment is any environment in LaTeX that acts like a list, e.g. `itemize`, `enumerate`, and `description`.  That said, I'm having a hard time translating your 'levels' idea to  your tabular environments.  Can you explain a bit more?  :(

Comment: Just added a few explanation. This "back-indent" (or how to call this?) could be done by press a few buttons manuallly. But is there a hot key for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand now.

There are at least two ways you can get at the behavior you need, assuming you are using AUCTeX (which you *should* be if you are writing LaTeX):

```
C-c ] runs the command LaTeX-close-environment, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `latex.el'.

It is bound to C-c ], <menu-bar> <LaTeX> <Close Environment>.

(LaTeX-close-environment &optional REOPEN)

Create an \end{...} to match the current environment.
With prefix-argument, reopen environment afterwards.
```

which will close the environment on a new line and advance point to the next line after that, or the even *more* convenient

```
C-c C-e runs the command LaTeX-environment, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `latex.el'.

It is bound to C-c C-e.

(LaTeX-environment ARG)

Make LaTeX environment (\begin{...}-\end{...} pair).
With optional ARG, modify current environment.

It may be customized with the following variables:

`LaTeX-default-environment'       Your favorite environment.
`LaTeX-default-style'             Your favorite document class.
`LaTeX-default-options'           Your favorite document class options.
`LaTeX-float'                     Where you want figures and tables to float.
`LaTeX-table-label'               Your prefix to labels in tables.
`LaTeX-figure-label'              Your prefix to labels in figures.
`LaTeX-default-format'            Format for array and tabular.
`LaTeX-default-width'             Width for minipage and tabular*.
`LaTeX-default-position'          Position for array and tabular.
```

Both of these ease the insertion of LaTeX environments and take care of the indentation.

Comment: It is :) I encourage you to read more about AUCTeX with `(info "AUCTeX")`; there is so much you can do with it.  If you work with citations, RefTeX is equally indispensable.  If your documents have a lot of mathematics, `preview-latex` (bundled with AUCTeX) comes in very handy.